# Is there a way to fix the Level 4 Merchant glitch

Tags: fallout-4

I'm playing Fallout 4 on Xbox, and there is this glitch that I've found to be quite common, but no one knows how to fix it. It's concerning the Merchants who can come to your settlement and are level 4 in selling stuff. I can find them on the road and trade with them, however, once I actually meet the requirements to let them join me, they either don't show up in random encounters or they don't have the dialogue option to come with me. I tried for days to make The Scribe or Smiling Larry spawn, but they wouldn't. And Doc Weathers won't come with me because there is no option to ask him to. I have also run into trouble with Rylee. I asked her to join me but she never showed up. I have found this to also be a common glitch. I don't know if it is a separate glitch or not. is there any way to find Rylee?

Comment: Those spawns are quite rare, they could be dead for all you know, killed off view. Not sure Doc Weathers can join you. The Scribe can for sure, he's the only one I ever recruited out of those mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

As fixes still seem to be non-existent, **I suggest trying [this mod](https://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/40747), *Level 4 Merchants Improved***: it places The Scribe, Ron Staples, Doc Anderson, and Smiling Larry in the [Dugout Inn](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Dugout_Inn), without removing the chance to encounter them randomly.

The Vault-Tec rep, Tina De Luca, Anne Hargraves and Trader Rylee can still be found at their original locations ([Hotel Rexford](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Hotel_Rexford), [Vault 81](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Vault_81), [WRVR broadcast station](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/WRVR_broadcast_station), and [Longneck Lukowski's Cannery](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Longneck_Lukowski's_Cannery), respectively).

Note that since this mod needs the Unofficial Patch, this is only a potential solution if you have all the DLCs. If not, [here](https://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/21849/)'s another mod that simply relocates the same four random encounter merchants to your position.

---

Additional notes:

- I reckoned the [Unofficial Patch](https://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/4598) would have fixed most of these issues, but was only able to find these ones specifically in the [changelog](https://www.afkmods.com/Unofficial%20Fallout%204%20Patch%20Version%20History.html):

  > - The player continues to ask the Vault-Tec Rep if he wants to work for them due to an incorrect condition check in the recruitment dialogue. (Bug #20297)
  > - The player continues to ask Anne Hargraves if she wants to work for them due to an incorrect condition check in the recruitment dialogue. (Bug #20296)
  > - The player continues to ask Trader Rylee if she wants to work for them due to an incorrect condition check in the recruitment dialogue.

  Not much help, I presume.
- Apart from their official requirements, these additional ones might help you out:

  > 1. You must have a highest level store already set up for them to assign to
  > 2. You must not be at maximum settler limit
  > 3. You must have at least two other level 3 vendors already active (I don't think it matters if you already have them assigned to regular settlers)
  > 4. I find that it works more smoothly if one of your other level 3's already in place is a Clinic or a Restaurant.
  >      <sup>([source](http://www.gamesas.com/dose-the-latest-patch-fix-the-lvl-merchantsvendors-t400848.html))</sup>